# how to add a select option which is child of another select in django html

Tags: python, html, django

Assume that I have 2 models: A and B

A is the main table and B is its sub (one-to-many relationships)

some of the contents in A have more than one subcategories in B
and some have no items in B

so, I want to display this contents in my HTML inside a select tag and the objective is when I choose an option from A I want the another select options to display the sub contents of A stored in B

what I know is

```
contents=A.objects.all()
```

and in html page

```
{for content in contents}
    <option value={{content.id}}>{{content}}</option>
{endfor}
```

but I don't know how to display the sub contents from B in another option which changes the sub contents according to the first option.

Comment: You can send an AJAX request when the option for the first list is chosen/changed. Send the selected option with your request and get the related options for it in the second list. Finally, use JavaScript to update the second list.

Comment: thank you very much 
actually i am new to web dev. 
so is there any sites available for reading about django - js- ajax integeration

Comment: Hey, I would suggest going through the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/). Also, you can search if there is a similar problem already asked on the stackoverflow. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to dynamically filter second select's options based on selected option in first select. There is a nice library called **[django-smart-selects](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects)** which uses **[ChainedForeignKey](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#chainedforeignkey-options)** relation. So for example if you have two models called **Country** and **City** and you want in your **City** select to filter cities based on the chosen **Country** you can simply do:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey

class Country(models.Model):
    .......

class City(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    .......

class Location(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    city = ChainedForeignKey(
        City,
        chained_field="country",
        chained_model_field="country",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    .......
```

You can install smart selects with `pip` by typing `pip install django-smart-selects`.